# Library not loaded after Runtime Hardened enabled

Tags: macos, dyld, notarize

I am trying to notarize my macOS app. My app is embedded with some licensed libraries.

I studied document about how to notarize an app and followed steps, my app can be uploaded to Apple notarize services and exported to use, but when I run my app it crashed. Under Xcode it shows

> "dyld: Library not loaded:........Reason: image not found".

I've tried several way to run my app successfully including make libraries Required/Optional under Linked Frameworks and Libraries and add my libraries to Embedded Binaries, unfortunately all failed. List conditions and environments below:

- Xcode version: 10.3 / 11
- macOS: 10.14.5/10.14.6
- Libraries signed: No
- Runtime Hardened chosen: Allow DYLD Environment Variables & Disable Library Validation

Below is piece of my library information:

```
Load command 8
      cmd LC_VERSION_MIN_MACOSX
  cmdsize 16
  version 10.11
      sdk 10.11
Load command 9
      cmd LC_SOURCE_VERSION
  cmdsize 16
  version 0.0
Load command 10
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name libMotionEngine-core.3.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 08:00:02 1970
      current version 3.1.4
compatibility version 3.0.0
Load command 11
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 48
         name /usr/lib/libc++.1.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 08:00:02 1970
      current version 120.1.0
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 12
          cmd LC_LOAD_DYLIB
      cmdsize 56
         name /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib (offset 24)
   time stamp 2 Thu Jan  1 08:00:02 1970
      current version 1226.10.1
compatibility version 1.0.0
Load command 13
      cmd LC_FUNCTION_STARTS
  cmdsize 16
  dataoff 54872
 datasize 320
Load command 14
      cmd LC_DATA_IN_CODE
  cmdsize 16
  dataoff 55192
 datasize 0
Load command 15
      cmd LC_CODE_SIGNATURE
  cmdsize 16
  dataoff 84352
 datasize 19696
```

Appreciation for any suggestion/opinions!

Comment: Same issue for me, have you find any solution?

Comment: The library's installed path has not been changed to hard-coded.  It is still relative (to `./`)